# Which is the first Hindu scripture that mentions zodiac signs by name?

Tags: india, hinduism, script

The following are the names of [zodiac signs](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=1&field_sarga_value=18&field_sloka_value=9)

1. Mesha (Aries),
2. Vrushabha (Taurus),
3. Mithuna (Gemini),
4. Karkat (Cancer),
5. Simha (Leo),
6. Kanya (Virgo),
7. Tula (Libra),
8. Vrushchika (Scorpio),
9. Dhanu (Sagittarius),
10. Makar (Capricorn),
11. Kumbha (Aquarius) and
12. Meena (Pisces).

---

Ramayana has an explicit mention of zodiac sign, in [Bala Kanda 18:9](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=1&field_sarga_value=18&field_sloka_value=9)

> in **karkata** lagna, when Brihaspati was in conjunction with the
> Moon.

So is Ramayana the first scripture to mention zodiac signs by name?

Which is the **first Hindu scripture**, other than Ramayana, according to the historical dating, that mentions zodiac signs by name?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question

Comment: @rajesh It's already asked there, look at the bountied questions